# Understanding two definitions of diffusion processes

Tags: stochastic-processes

1. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_process):

   > **A diffusion process** is a Markov process with continuous sample paths for which the Kolmogorov forward equation is the Fokker-Planck
   >   equation.

   I was wondering if "for which the Kolmogorov forward equation is the
   Fokker-Planck equation" is redundant and therefore can be removed, because if I am correct, [the
   Fokker-Planck equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker-Planck_equation) is the same thing as the Kolmogorov forward
   equation.
2. From Lamperti's Stochastic Processes:

   > The transition function of a Brownian motion or Wiener process satisfy $$ p_t(x, [x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon]) = 1-o(t) $$ for every
   >   $\epsilon >0$ and every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This means that the
   >   Wiener process never stands still, but is in constant motion. The
   >   condition, however, implies that the process changes state not by
   >   jumps but by continuous motion. A Markov process with this property
   >   is called **a diffusion**.

   Suppose a stochastic process (Markovian or not necessarily Markovian) satisfies $$ p_t(x, [x-\epsilon,
       x+\epsilon]) = 1-o(t) $$ for every $\epsilon >0$ and every $x \in
       \mathbb{R}$.

   - Why does it never stand still, but is in constant motion? If a process takes a constant value $x$ over all times and outcomes, it
     still satisfies the condition, doesn't it?
   - The condition, however, implies that the process changes state not by jumps but by continuous motion. Does it mean the condition implies the process is continuous a.s.?
3. Is Lamperti's definition stronger than Wikipedia's definition?

Thanks and regards!